# Can you create a secret using kubectl --from-literal flag where the value is a JSON

Tags: json, kubectl

I am attempting to create a kubectl secret using the following command on a Windows box.

```
kubectl create secret generic dest-svc-key --from-literal=secret='<JSON Payload>'
```

I have two questions:

1. One of the fields in the JSON is a certificate e.g.

```
"verificationKey": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----  some data   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

This results in an error
error: bad flag syntax:....
Is there a way to let kubectl know that it is not a flag and just a string?

2. Since we are passing a JSON as an argument (e.g  --from-literal=secret='{"tenantmode": "dedicated"}) we are getting an error
   error: exactly one NAME is required, got 2

Is there a way I can rewrite the kubectl command? I came across a command

```
kubectl create secret generic secretname --from-literal "someJsonKey=$(cat somejsonfile.json)"
```

But can this be implemented in Windows? Installing an emulator like Cygwin unfortunately is not an option.

Regards,
Prabal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, In Windows you can do this:

```
kubectl create secret generic secretname --from-literal "someJsonKey=$(cat somejsonfile.json)"
```

Windows:

```
# Read the contents of the JSON file
$jsonContent = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\path\to\somejsonfile.json"

# Create secret
kubectl create secret generic secretname --from-literal="someJsonKey=$jsonContent"
```

or

```
kubectl create secret generic secretname --from-file=path/to/bar
```